# node modules not getting installed

Tags: angular, npm

I got the latest project code from my org tfs. I did a `npm install` but it fails with the below error.

```
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx> npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: xxx@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@2.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"2.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=2.4.2 <2.7" from @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler-cli@"5.2.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-09T15_02_32_661Z-debug.log
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx>
```

What cause this issue? It's not happening on my colleague's pc.

Here are my node infos

```
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx> npm -v
7.6.1
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx> node -v
v14.16.0
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx> npm info
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xxx - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'xxx@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-09T14_45_17_253Z-debug.log
PS C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx>
```

**UPDATE #1**
So instead of checking why `npm install` fails. I logged in to tfs went to the project location, downloaded the node_modules and pasted in the local project. after that I ran `npm rebuild node-sass` and `npm run sim` (configured to run with a simulator api service). still not able to run the application

```
C:\Repo\source_code_2\xxx>npm run sim

> xxx@0.0.1 sim
> cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=simulator "npm run _runStandalone"


> xxx@0.0.1 _runStandalone
> npm run _authenticateLocal && webpack-dev-server --config webpack.ng.js


> xxx@0.0.1 _authenticateLocal
> node ./scripts/serve-before.js

CONFIGURING AUTHENTICATION FOR STANDALONE APP.  ENVIRONMENT: simulator
[PROXY] Proxying all WAS requests to http://localhost:44309/
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /remoteWAS  ->  http://localhost:44309/
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/remoteWAS" ~> ""
Project is running at http://localhost:4200/
webpack output is served from /
404s will fallback to /index.html
 11% building modules 13/17 modules 4 active ...d\node_modules\webpack\hot\emitter.jswebpack: wait until bundle finished: /
Hash: 4b285717fb0b3db6f17e
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 19417ms
 25 assets
   [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/app/main.ts 40 bytes {main} [built]
   [1] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/polyfills.ts 40 bytes {polyfills} [built]
   [2] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/app/app.scss ./node_modules/@wfm/web-theme/font/ge-icon.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css 64 bytes {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/@wfm/web-theme/font/ge-icon.css] ./node_modules/@wfm/web-theme/font/ge-icon.css 1.13 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 8.86 kB {inline} [built]
[./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css] ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css 1.11 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??embedded!./node_modules/@wfm/web-theme/font/ge-icon.css] ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/@wfm/web-theme/font/ge-icon.css 47.4 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??embedded!./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css] ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css 119 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/app/app.scss] ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/app/app.scss 566 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {inline} [built]
[./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js] ./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js 9.46 kB {styles} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:4200] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 7.93 kB {inline} [built]
[./src/app/app.scss] ./src/app/app.scss 1.35 kB {styles} [built]
[./src/app/main.ts] ./src/app/main.ts 0 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/polyfills.ts] ./src/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {polyfills} [built]
    + 22 hidden modules

ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 651 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below commands.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm init 
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```